# What is the Property for "Text inside label" in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Suppose my text is "Hello have a nice day", so I want only **nice** text is in label

```xml
 <Text text="Hello have a "><Label text="nice"></Label>"day"</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

`text`is property of `Label` control, not an aggregation.

To set text of `Label` you can simply do:

```
<Label text="Hello World" />
```

Comment: my sentence is  "Hello have a nice day..!!"  In this sentence can we set "nice" text is in label..??

Comment: Yes, surely! As I have mentioned in the snippet you just need to set `text` property of `Label`.
You should not put `Label` inside Text control, as `Text` does not have any aggregation. `Text` control itself has `text` property too.

Comment: I tried its not working.. can you share one example..?  And I want only **nice** text is label

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this,
but [here](http://jsbin.com/nunujas/1/edit?html,output) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sap.m.Label`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Label/properties) control has in fact a `text` property, so you define the text as

```xml
<Label text="Label text" />
```

Similarly the [`sap.m.Text`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Text/properties) control has a `text` property, so you define the text as

```xml
<Text text="Text text" />
```

However the Text control does not have an aggregation for other Controls, so you cannot nest a Label inside a Text.